# Uploaded File not Posting

Tags: c#, javascript, forms, post, file-upload

I'm using the upload form below to post to a page that processes the file using the code below. However, the file isn't showing up. I get count 0 with no files posted.... Am I missing something in the form post? I know it's fairly specific as to what must be used when files are uploaded. I've included further info below as well.

Form

```
<form id="importform" method="POST" target="uploadframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AJAX/Import_Subprocess_Content/RAC_Connolly_ImportSession.aspx">
                                        <input type="file" id="importfile" onchange="fileselected()"/>
                                        <input type="button" value="Import File" onclick="uploadfile();" />
                                    </form>
```

Server-Side Code

```
  protected void Page_Load()
        {
            Response.Write(Request.Files.Count);
        }
```

Further Information

The form is posted via javascript using `.submit()`

The file input is `visibility:hidden`

the button first calls the `click()` of the file input

`onchange` the file input calls the `submit()` of the form

**UPDATE**: Tried removing the hidden attribute, but it did not correct the issue.

Comment: I think hidden (by css) fields are not posted. Try removing the hidden style.

Comment: @HasanKhan I tried it, but it didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File required a name attribute to be uploaded. When given the name attribute, another problem arises with IE7, the inability to post forms via javascript when uploading files. Had to default to using submit button rather than onchange event.

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually doing the file upload. You need to add the code to the Import File button.

This code looks to the file field, checks it has a file and then says only the type of CSV can be uploaded. It then proceeds to save the file in to /datafiles folder on the web server.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (file.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (file.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/octet-stream")
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/datafiles/") + filename);
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblStatus.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblStatus.Text = "Upload status: Only .CSV files are accepted! This is a " + file.PostedFile.ContentType + " file";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblStatus.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```